# ¿Cómo comprobar datos al sobreescribir un valor del modelo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Estoy programando un modelo que depende de otro y quiero que al modificar un campo especifico, este cree un objeto nuevo a raíz de la información modificada.

Mis modelos son:

### Pedido

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    f_ped = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    cp_nom_producto = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    estado_pedido = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES_ESTADO_PEDIDO, default = CHOICES_ESTADO_PEDIDO[0][0])
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil)
    valoracion = models.OneToOneField(Valoracion, blank=True, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_guia = models.CharField(max_length = 12, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_entrega = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_transaccion = models.CharField(max_length = 36, blank=True, null=True)
    facturado = models.BooleanField(default = False)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.id:
        hash = hashlib.sha256(str(self.id).encode('utf-8'))
        unique_slugify(self, hash.hexdigest())
        super(Pedido, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    elif not self.id:
        super(Pedido, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

### Linea Pedido

```
class LineaPedido(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estado = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES_ESTADO_PEDIDO)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Cuando el campo Pedido.estado_pedido cambie quiero crear un objeto LineaPedido con la información del pedido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que hacer lo que quieres no es muy complicado. Para saber si alguna propiedad o campo de tu modelo u objeto cambió, supongo que puedes saberlo en el método `save()` que se encargaría de guardar el nuevo estado en memoria del objeto. Pero ahí mismo puedes consultar el estado anterior del objeto, de esta forma: (también te muestro una forma más fácil de sobreescribir tu método `save` eliminando redundancias)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk:  # Mejor preguntar por el primary_key que por el ID
        # de esta forma sabemos si está o no en la base de datos
        # no sé de qué serán estas dos líneas, pero las conservo
        hash = hashlib.sha256(str(self.id).encode('utf-8'))
        unique_slugify(self, hash.hexdigest())

        anterior = self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        if anterior.estado_pedido != self.estado_pedido:
            # creas el nuevo objeto
            LineaPedido.objects.create(pedido=self, estado=self.estado)
    # no es necesario poner un else, se entiende que si no entra al condicional, no existe en la base de datos
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Espero haberte ayudado con esto, cualquier duda, pregunta o inconveniente, puedes comentar de vuelta y te seguiré ayudando